# There was a potential harmful file on my server, What damage has it done?

Tags: php, wordpress

I received an abuse complaint for my server from hosting provider. After a thorough search I found file with name "title.php" in a WordPress installation's upload directory.

I am curious to know what kind of damage it may have done to my server/website?

http://pastebin.com/r7CdCizX

Comment: To clarify, code was encrypted, which I decrypt before pasting.

Comment: Looks like a PHP SMTP client. Probably a way to use your server to forward spam.

Comment: Do you have PHP installed on your server? If you don't have the software installed, then it's my understanding that the PHP script you found would be unable to execute, and if that's the case then you may not have gotten to much damage.

Answer (score 2):

It is clearly a spamming component. There's lots of mail sending functions around the code:

```
private function mailPassthru($to, $subject, $body, $header, $params) { 

public function isSMTP() 

public function isMail()

public function isSendmail()

public function isQmail()
```

This generally occurs when you have an outdated Wordpress installation laying around. There are lots of bots out there scanning for vulnerable Wordpress and its plugins.

You should disinfect your installation. [This](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-clean-up-wordpress-installation) and [this](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) will provide some pointers to follow.

After cleaning and reinstalling, keep watching the Wordpress dashboard for updates, and update everything as soon as there is a new version available. Otherwise you will be infected again.